# Why have Apache Solr chosen Jetty as a Servlet container

Tags: tomcat, solr, jetty

I'm hesitating to deploy `Apache Solr` to `Jetty` or `Apache Tomcat`. I know that Jetty is lignter than Tomcat and that Tomcat is more robust when there is a lot of queries coming.

So I need to know why Solr have chosen Jetty as its default Servlet container? maybe that can help me to choose between the two of them.

Comment: It is a bit of a fallacy to say tomcat is more robust when there are lots of queries are coming in.  Servlet containers from api perspective are largely commodity at this point, distinguishing in other ways like protocol support (jetty is first to support SPDY for example) and ease of use (tomcat has an administrative app) or ease to embed, osgi support, etc etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably it is because it is "light" and can be easily embedded on the Solr distribution... so you can immediately have a running Solr server without requiring any other Servlet container (such as Tomcat, etc.). In terms of performance, not sure there will be such a big difference. Probably this depends on your own setup, for example in "development" I use Jetty, in production I use Tomcat, since I already am using it for other applications...

Answer (score 1):

Jetty is often used as a default stand-alone servlet container in various project because it is light and easy to use.

You can see the list of projects using Jetty by default here:
http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/powered/

Answer (score 0):

I understand from this thread that it's adviced to use Jetty cause it's the one shipped with Solr, and the one they have tested against: [What are some Servlet Container pros and cons for a Solr installation?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11516225/2228912).

Comment: If you read the accepted answer on that discussion you see that both are referred as "suitable" options... in the specific link you send you see a lot of discussion on trying to keep Solr "agnostic" so any Servlet container could be used... so this is again the same: both will do, it will depend on your situation/setup... even preferences (as someone refers on that thread).